# Is it "convince someone to" or "convince someone of"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, differences

I've always thought that the use of the preposition 'to' with the verb 'convince' is correct. But I recently learned from a reliable source that 'to' shouldn't be used with 'convince' but rather with 'persuade'. So instead of saying for instance 'I should try to convince him to work harder', I'd rather say 'I should try to convince him of his ability to work harder' or 'I should try to convince him that he can work harder' or 'I should persuade him to work harder.'

Honestly, I'm still perplexed. Could anyone shed some light?

Comment: Grammatically, *convince to* and *convince of* are both correct and have different meanings. Why would you have difficulty in using one over the other if the meaning you want to convey is clear? Expressing a thought in different ways, all grammatically correct, is but a matter of style. See related usage in corpora and it becomes clear.

Comment: Why don't you have a look at Oald which gives you the main constructions of to convince.  http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/convince?q=convince

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** they're both fine, and you clearly already understand when to use which.

Use *of* with a noun phrase, *to* with a predicate, and *that* for a clause. You gave very good examples of all three in your question. The original reason the *to* usage was frowned upon is that *convince* was supposedly only for thoughts and ideas; if something someone said resulted in you actually doing something, then you were *persuaded* rather than *convinced*. This rule is rather old. Here's what *Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of English Usage* has to say:

> To sum up: long ago *persuade* became established in a use connoting mental acceptance without following action -- a sense Richard Grant White thought should be reserved for *convince*. *Persuade* still has this use, often with the same *of* and *that* constructions regularly found with *convince*. Sometime around the middle of this century, *convince* began to be used to connote mental acceptance followed by action, usually in a construction in which an infinitive phrase follows the verb [that is, with *to*]. This construction is now a fully established idiom. The earlier usage writers who tried to fence off *persuade* from *convince* and the later ones who tried to fence off *convince* from *persuade* have failed alike. And in another generation perhaps no one will care.

You can read the rest of the entry on page 297 [on Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=2yJusP0vrdgC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false). They also give attested usages from the New York Times, etc.

Eduardo may have a point about the British/American thing. Just a quick search of the [BYU-BNC British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) and the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), which contain millions of words from published material gave this for the BNC:

- 7 hits for *convince him to*
- 12 hits for *convince him of*
- 39 hits for *convince him that*

and this for the COCA:

- 140 hits for *convince him to*
- 29 hits for *convince him of*
- 131 hits for *convince him that*

Keep in mind that each of these usages differs also in *meaning*, so be careful what conclusions you draw from these numbers.

You may also be interested in the [Google Ngram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams).

Comment: Thank you for the valuable answer. In fact, I've also checked in the online corpus concordances output and I was surprised I didn't find any entry with 'convince to'. Here's the link http://conc.lextutor.ca/concordancers/wwwassocwords.pl

Comment: @TeHbTeHb: Sorry, your link is not correct. Need to access through http://conc.lextutor.ca/concordancers/concord_e.html. Lextutor gives this result for 'convince to': '...he sought to **convince** another National League club **to** move here.'

Answer (score 10):

In "convince him to" or "persuade him to", "to" is not a preposition — it's part of the infinitive verb that follows.  "Convince him to (verb)" is a legitimate construction.  The "of" form takes a noun — "convince him of (some fact/position/etc)".

Comment: Of course it is not a preposition. What a blunder! Silly me. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: It's not part of the infinitive either though. It's a subordinator. In sentences like *make him go,* the verb *go* is infinitive, but there's not a *to* in sight.

Answer (score 4):

Examples taken from [merrian-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/convince) defition of *convince* include both the use of *of* and *to*:

> He convinced me that the story was true.
>   They convinced us of their innocence.
>   I managed to convince myself that I was doing the right thing.
>   We convinced them to go along with our scheme.
>   I was unable to convince her to stay.

However, according to [thesaurus](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/convince):

> The use of convince to talk about persuading someone to do something
>   is considered by many British speakers to be wrong or unacceptable. It
>   would be preferable to use an alternative such as persuade or talk
>   into.
>
> So it would seem to be just another BrE/AmE usage issue.
>
> The definition in the [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/convince) also points in
>   that direction:
>
> 1. (may take a clause as object) to make (someone) agree, understand, or realize the truth or validity of something; persuade
> 2. **Chiefly US** to persuade (someone) to do something

Besides this usage issue, there is also, as JohnJamesSmith said, a difference in meaning.
Here is an interesting discussion at WordReference, which gives a very good example, concluding that there are cases where the replacement of *convince* for *persuade* just for the sake of *correctness*, can eventually have an actual degradation in meaning. Let me quote the [post](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1885931):

> I actually feel like there's a meaningful difference between convince
>   someone to do something and persuade someone to do something, at least
>   in certain contexts.
>
> Since convince, as you say, geostan, involves changing someone's
>   beliefs or opinions, I feel like that semantic property holds even for
>   the convince someone to construction. Let me give you an example:
>
> Two friends, Bob and George, get caught stealing from a store. Bob is
>   always getting into trouble, whereas George is generally a nice boy.
>   When questioned by his parents, George says, "I know it was wrong to
>   steal, but Bob convinced me to!"
>
> In this context, convinced implies, at least to me, that George
>   changed his beliefs, at least temporarily, in order to steal. That is,
>   for that brief moment, Bob managed to make George believe that it was
>   okay to steal, or that he could ignore his conscience/beliefs.
>
> Persuaded, on the other hand, would imply that George stole knowing
>   (and still believing) full well that it was wrong.
>
> It may not be a great example, but if you consider the adjectives
>   convincing and persuasive, I think the difference is there. We could
>   say that "Bob was convincing" means that Bob was able to convince
>   George that stealing was okay, whereas "Bob was persuasive" simply
>   means Bob was able to get George to steal, without having him change
>   his beliefs.

So, I would conclude that in most cases it is a matter of BrE or AmE use, but you should always bear in mind that you can not *always* replace *convince* with *persuade*, because both verbs have slightly different meanings.

Comment: Sorry to tell you that the example didn't really make me see the difference between 'convince' and 'persuade' although I 'feel' there's indeed a difference. e.g 'The bad weather persuaded me to change plans and stay home.' I don't feel 'convince' appropriate here and excuse my ignorance I don't know why.